history.replacestate only working for ID but not Classes for URL
I'm using anchor links that I don't want to update the URL after clicking them. For example not adding #anc-a at the end of the URL. I got it working with multiple IDs like this:
HTML:
<a target="_self" id="anchor-a" href="#anc-a">Anchor A</a>
<a target="_self" id="anchor-b" href="#anc-b">Anchor B</a>
<a target="_self" id="anchor-c" href="#anc-c">Anchor C</a>

JS:
document.getElementById('anchor-a').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
location.hash = event.target.getAttribute('href').substr(1);
history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
});
document.getElementById('anchor-b').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
location.hash = event.target.getAttribute('href').substr(1);
history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
});
document.getElementById('anchor-c').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
location.hash = event.target.getAttribute('href').substr(1);
history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
});

This removes the # at the end when clicking an anchor link so that the URL stays as index.html like I want it to.
But when I tried to use getElementsByClassName or querySelectorAll instead of getElementById it doesn't work. It changes the URL with the # at the end like this: index.html#anc-a, #anc-b or #anc-c which I don't want.
Here is a list of what I've tried changing getElementById to:
Replacing ID with class="anchors" in <a>:
document.getElementsByClassName('anchors')
document.getElementsByClassName('.anchors')
document.querySelectorAll("anchors")
document.querySelectorAll(".anchors")

And with the three original IDs:
document.querySelectorAll("anchor-a, anchor-b, anchor-c")
document.querySelectorAll("#anchor-a, #anchor-b, #anchor-c")

Any tips on how to get class or selector working instead of ID as I will be using many anchor links?
Edit:
For anyone having the same problem, this solved it:
document.querySelectorAll('.anchors').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        location.hash = event.target.getAttribute('href').substr(1);
        history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
    });
});


a commonly asked duplicate question. both getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll do not return an element but a list of elements. The first returns an HTML Collection Object and the later a Node List. So you need to threat the returned list as a list of elements not as a single element.

Maybe, I read it but don't understand it fully. I want to change ID to class or selector but that doesn't work as intended for the URL. Your link suggests an array as well, maybe that would work?

What exactly do you not understand by it? The thing is that both are just array-like objects. As such normal array methods do not work on them. The latter (querySelectorAll) can use forEach as an iteration method while the first requires either transforming it into an array or iterating with a for loop. As you work with a list then, you need to always iterate through the list to get every single element.
